# Sum every second digit in a number

Tags: code-golf, math, number

I have a number like this:

```
n = 548915381
```

The output should be the sum of every second digit of that number. In this case 26:

```
4+9+5+8 = 26
```

Rules:

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.
- The input consists only of numbers bigger than 10 (at least 2 digits) but smaller than a 32-bit integer.
- The input will be a number, not a string

Test cases:

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 0 |
| 101011 | 1 |
| 548915381 | 26 |
| 999999 | 27 |
| 2147483647 | 29 |
| 999999999 | 36 |

Comment: Can we take input either as a string or a digit array?

Comment: Technically, it should be a number. Take whichever is closer in said programming language

Comment: While we advise against accepting an answer in the first place to [code-golf] challenges, as it gives the impression that the challenge is "over", if you do accept an answer, it's recommended to wait longer than a day, to give everyone enough opportunity to participate.

Comment: The formulation is ambiguous. At first, I thought the first two outputs would be 1 and 3, for example… The chosen order defining "every second digit" isn't "natural" in programming terms.

Comment: Every second digit "in a number". I know it sounds weird, but I couldn't think of any better way to phrase it. If you think that any other formulation would make more sense, please let me know. I guess you could say the digits "at even positions" but then you have to set an ambiguous first position. Is the first one even (0) or odd (1). Most programming languages start counting from 0, so that would make even less sense in my personal opinion. People counting would start counting from 1 though

Comment: Does it mean that for some loose type languages that take their inputs as string such as PHP in command line, it needs an explicit conversion? Should the conversion be counted in the score?

Comment: A specification shouldn't be inferred from test cases. Since there's only one input for which it's different, I actually assumed it takes digits from right to left until I saw the first answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
y∑
```

well.

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ54oiRIiwiIiwiNTQ4OTE1MzgxIl0=) | [1 byte with `s`](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwieSIsIiIsIjU0ODkxNTM4MSJd)

**Explanation**

```
y∑
y   Uninterleave, push two lists with every second and every second+1 digit
 ∑  Sum the first list
```

Comment: Wouldn’t that by 4 bytes? ∑ takes 3 bytes in UTF-8, 2 bytes in UTF-16 (but then y takes 2 bytes too).

Comment: @Lazy Vyxal uses a custom ([SBCS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS)) character set, which means it has 64 single-byte characters.

Comment: Ah, good to know.

Comment: Why is the `s` solution not primary?

Comment: @Adám I kinda want to have a 1-byte answer, but I feel like that's cheating

Comment: @mathcat Why would a 1-byte answer be cheating? What if the challenge was to add two numbers? Would `+` be cheating too?

Comment: @Adám This is really subjective, but I don't think I count `s` as a flag.

Answer (score 9):

### Python 3, <strike>28 37 32 30</strike> 35 bytes

```
lambda n:sum(map(int,str(n)[1::2]))
```

Assuming input is a <strike>string</strike> number

Comment: You might want to include a link, eg. [ato](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhb7chJzk1ISFfKsiktzNXITCzQy80p08qINrayMYjU1IYo2FhQBRTXSgHIFpSUamjDxBStNTSwsDU2NLQwhAgA)

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

*-1 by [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

```javascript
f=n=>n&&f(i=n/10|0)+i++%2*n%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYzRCsIgGEbve4rdbGhS@qtTd2HvMtYMY@ho0VXvbjYagQR93@U5nGv/6Jfh5uf7IcTzmJKzwZ5C0zjkbaDAngwTT0jN96EGloYYljiNxylekEMAGFfbKK3YruDsH8/fGplDwVtpOmiFWZXMuSqEbt03wHUhcJBaGqGkztJb6H4WPpEsCJVe)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n?f(n/10|0)+i++%2*n%10:i=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczfCsIgFMfx@55iNwNNSo86/wTWs4w1wxgaLbrq3c3GIpDOufx@@F37Zz8P93B77GI6jzl7F90xnjyKFNiLYRIIafk2tsAOwbE8pDinadxP6YI8AoZx8z1KG7ape3lYTelQ9U4aC50wCymdqwrY5X4DXFeAg9TSCCV1QR9g/y6sIwUIld8)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = n =>            // f is a recursive function taking the input n
  n ?               // if n is not equal to 0:
    f(n / 10 | 0) + //   do a recursive call with floor(n / 10)
                    //   it's important to understand that:
                    //     1) n is defined in the local scope of f
                    //     2) i is defined in the global scope
                    //     3) we're not going to execute the code that
                    //        follows until the recursion stops and i
                    //        has been initialized
    i++ % 2 *       //   take the parity of i (increment it afterwards)
    n % 10          //   and multiply by the least significant decimal
                    //   digit of n
  :                 // else:
    i = 0           //   stop the recursion and initialize i to 0
```

Comment: [30](https://tio.run/##bcxNDsIgEIbhvafopg1IFAYoPwu8S1OLwTRgrHHl3RGbGhPizPJ98l2H57CM93B7HGI6Tzl7F90pdp1HwUUK7MUwCYS0fB9bYHlMcUnzdJzTBXkEDOPme5Q2bFf38rCZ0qHqvTQWemFWUjpXFbDr/Qa4rgAHqaURSuqCPsD@XdhGChAqvwE)

Answer (score 8):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```raku
{sum m:g/.<(./}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/urg0VyHXKl1fz0ZDT7/2f3FipUKahrZetEGspoKtnYJetGGsQlp@kUJOZl5qsZ2dXnl@UUrxf0MDTk4DLkMDIDTk5DTksgQDTk4jcy4jQxNzEwtjMxNzTiNLqARIztgMAA)

Simple regex based sum of every other digit

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-hx`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ì ó
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWh4&code=7CDz&input=NTQ4OTE1Mzgx)

```
ì ó     :Implicit input of integer
ì       :Convert to digit array
  ó     :Uninterleave
        :Implicit output of sum of last element
```

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 36 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe).*

```
\(x)sum(x%/%10^(nchar(x):0)%%10*1:0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3VWI0KjSLS3M1KlT1VQ0N4jTykjMSi4BiVgaaqkABLUMgA6o2PE3D0EBTmdOAC8QAQkMgxxDIMTWxsDQ0NbYA8Y3MgAKWYADimQN5RoYm5iYWxmYm5iARS7g8RImxGcT4BQsgNAA)

Comment: [38](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0KjSLS3M1NCpU9VUNDeI08pIzEouAglYGmqpAAU0tQyALqjo8TQMoosxpwAViAKEhkGMI5JiaWFgamhpbgPhGZkABSzAA8cyBPCNDE3MTC2MzE3OQiCVcHqLE2Axi_IIFEBoA)

Comment: @Giuseppe nice one, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <sup><s>39</s></sup> 32 bytes

-7 (pxeger suggested lambda)

```python
lambda n:sum(map(int,`n`[1::2]))
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfaBvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyM3sUAjM69EJyEvIdrQysooVlPzf0ERUEQhUcPQQJMLwQZCQwTf1MTC0tDU2AJJyBIMEHwjQxNzEwtjMxNzdDUgZf8B)

<sub>EDIT: new test cases</sub>

Comment: You can shorten this by using a lambda: `lambda n:sum(map(int,\`n\`[1::2]))`

Answer (score 7):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 33 bytes

```bash
for _ c (`fold -1`)let t+=c;<<<$t
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3FdPyixTiFZIVNBLS8nNSFHQNEzRzUksUSrRtk61tbGxUSiAKoeoXrDIyNDE3sTA2MzGHiAAA)

-3 bytes thanks to roblogic

Inputs as a string, because there is no way to input as a number in Zsh.

Comment: Not bad, I would have done, `for j k (${(s::)1})((s+=k));<<<$s` for [33 bytes...](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhY3FdPyixSyFLIVNFSqNYqtrDQNazU1NIq1bbM1Na1tbGxUiiEKoepXR5uaWFgamhpbGMZChQA)

Answer (score 7):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 14 bytes

```
0i~i:c%@0(?n+!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yCzLtMqWdXBQMM@T1vx/38jQxNzEwtjMxNzAA)

**Explanation**

```
0               # init sum as 0
 i~             # discard an input
   i:           # duplicate an input
     c%@        # mod the copy by 12 and move down on stack
        0(?n    # if the other copy was negative, print the sum
            +!  # else add copy to sum and skip the next instruction
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel), <sup><s>39</s></sup> 32 bytes

- -7 bytes thanks to [Engineer Toast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38183/engineer-toast)!

```c
=SUM(--(0&MID(A1,2*ROW(A:A),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: You can get it down to 32 bytes by not worrying about how long the string is and handling the blank strings instead: `=SUM(--(0&MID(A1,2*ROW(A:A),1)))`

Comment: @EngineerToast very cool!

Answer (score 7):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <strike>10</strike> 7 bytes

```
$+@SUWa
```

First pip answer, so don't sue me plz.

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIkK0BTVVdhIiwiIiwiNTQ4OTE1MzgxIiwiIl0=)

**Explanation**

```
$+@SUWa
  @SUWa  Uninterweave a, take the second item of the two "every second element" lists 
$+       Sum the string
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCIkKyhVV2EpQDEiLCIiLCI1NDg5MTUzODEiLCItcCJd)

Comment: 7 bytes: `$+@SUWa`

Comment: Why would anyone sue you for being awesome? ;^) @Steffan, that's really clever! A couple alternate 7 byters for completeness: `$+@RUWa` or `$+DQUWa`. (Also, `$+*SUWa` and `S$+*UWa` technically output as a singleton list, but it looks the same without flags.)

Comment: @Steffan huh wow okaay. So @ can be used to convert a number to a string?

Comment: @mathcat No LMAO. `SU` returns all but the first item, so the second item contained in a list. Then `@` gets the first item.

Comment: @mathcat Numbers and strings are the same data type in Pip, so no conversion is needed. (This is sometimes a blessing and sometimes a curse.)

Comment: @Steffan I think you meant to say `S` returns all but the first item (`SUW` = `S UW`).

Comment: @DLosc lool right everything in pip is Scala™

Comment: Challenge is currently too new to bounty, so I'll do it later (remind me if I forget)

Comment: @Steffan bounty :P?

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 18 bytes

```perl
s/.(.)/$\+=$1/ge}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX09DT1NfJUbbVsVQPz21tvr/fyNDE3MTC2MzE/N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Input via STDIN.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>40</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/18535/g-b)
-1 byte thanks to [Armand Fardeau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94303/armand-fardeau)

```ruby
->n{eval"#{n}".scan(/.(.)/)*?+}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhb7de3yqlPLEnOUlKvzapX0ipMT8zT09TT0NPU1tey1ayGq1hUouEWbmlhYGpoaWxjGQgQXLIDQAA)

Comment: You can get 30 bytes with `-n` flag: `gsub(/.(.)/){$.+=eval$1};p$.-1`

Comment: Shorter version (31 bytes):
`->n{eval"#{n}".scan(/.(.)/)*?+}`

https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0BBw0hPzzDVTFMvN7GgWiHeUEFfwVChpgbCAhK1//8DAA

Comment: @ArmandFardeau Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
tssM%2+1z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v6S42FfVSNuw6v9/I0MTcxMLYzMTcwA)

```
      +1z    # Append '1' before the input
    %2       # Every 2nd element of
 ssM         # Map to integer and take sum
t            # Decrease by 1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
D0ÐoS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/F4PCE/OD/h9s1I///NzTQUTA0AEJDHQVTEwtLQ1NjCyDTEgx0FIwMTcxNLIzNTMxhYkAAAA)

Also 5 bytes

```
DŻm2S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6O5co@D/h9s1I///NzTQUTA0AEJDHQVTEwtLQ1NjCyDTEgx0FIwMTcxNLIzNTMxhYkAAAA)

Also also 5 bytes

```
Ds2SṪ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@l2Cj44c5V/w@3a0b@/29ooKNgaACEhjoKpiYWloamxhZApiUY6CgYGZqYm1gYm5mYw8SAAAA)

#### How they work

```
D0ÐoS - Main link. Takes an integer on the left
D     - Digits
  Ðo  - To digits in odd positions:
 0    -   Set them to 0
    S - Sum
```

```
DŻm2S - Main link. Takes an integer on the left
D     - Digits
 Ż    - Prepend a zero
  m2  - Take every second element
    S - Sum
```

```
Ds2SṪ - Main link. Takes an integer on the left
D     - Digits
 s2   - Slice into pairs
   S  - Sums
    Ṫ - Tail
```

Comment: Isn't [D0ÐoS](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos) another language invented by Dennis? ;^)

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
!n=sum(i->i-'0',"$n"[2:2:end])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1NCoMwFITX5hTPUDCCFuO/Qtx10TOULmJN4RWbilFw4d1t0NKZzcx8i3nNPUq@bJurhZnfDMMGQy/yAnrS9BbXca10d/e352cEBNQwKtn1qJVhPgErGbQgYJCjUWd21VNghh4nhv6BhxH11GsmRePKY3IlCAEtrOuf0ssyqMekOqBB6xN7ufEInIjwyJqDw0mWlhXPktKWOCfVLhsLEvO0SMskTwtbqx/ZYZJ/AQ)

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 25 bytes

```factor
[ >dec <odds> 48 v-n Σ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9LTsMwEIb3PsVkT5xn8wJF6gYUCXVTsUIoCo6TVGrsYE8KCHEa7sOVQuq0pf9sRt/882oqhlJNT9ti85CB5m8jF4zr/4zyD1SVhr7Cjg6V0lwt@YEfO0@FUeyYrDkMiiN@DmonEG6h2GTQyn1D1o/FeptBXnMGYuxfuco1zqYWwIJ7cwK4NE3BtufNHDrEQWeOU0umaWPqx/FUqtZhUiAX6LxLVdtl2WJZzmNvru6jHfZ7Qr4IzPJcuMgC98Tm8M7MM2wVJqm3ChLPMD8yMDU6G/3YQN8L4zAJojA2ML1yLmYLgoh8k@l5efhO1rXOIUzgYAv4/YGXqa8GoNMf)

```
       ! 548915381
>dec   ! "548915381"
<odds> ! "4958"
48     ! "4958" 48
v-n    ! { 4 9 5 8 }
Σ      ! 26
```

Answer (score 5):

## [flax](https://github.com/pygamer0/flax), 2 bytes

```
ΣẎ
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJmbGF4IiwiIiwizqPhuo4iLCLPgiciLCIiLCJbWzEwLDEwMTAxMSw1NDg5MTUzODEsOTk5OTk5LDIxNDc0ODM2NDcsOTk5OTk5OTk5XV0iXQ==)

Answer (score 5):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 15 bytes

All credit goes to [Raul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72244/rdm).

```
[:+/_2}.\,.&.":
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxPtpKWz_eqFYvRkdPTU_JCiJ6016TKzU5I19BI826LlZTzU7B0ACIgNBQwdTEwtLQ1NjCUMESDBSMDE3MTSyMzUzMoSJAADFmwQIIDQA)

```
[:+/_2}.\,.&.":
         ,.&.":  NB. equivalent to ". ,. ": y, convert to digit list
    _2}.\        NB. behead each non-overlapping window of size 2
[:+/             NB. sum the resulting column
```

## My original 19 bytes from 11 bytes

```
1(#.]*0 1$~#),.&.":
```

Updated to reflect challenge requirements. Thanks to Jonah for the modifications.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmux2VBDWS9Wy0DBUKVOWVNHT01PyQoic9Nekys1OSNfQSPNui5WU81OwRCoygAIDRVMTSwsDU2NLQwVLMFAwcjQxNzEwtjMxBwqAgQQYxYsgNAA)

```
1(#.]*0 1$~#),.&.":
             ,.&.":  NB. same as above
1(          )        NB. dyadic hook
           #         NB. use length of right arg to
      0 1$~          NB. reshape 0 1, reuses elements to create alternating 1's
    ]*               NB. multiply by the right arg
  #.                 NB. 1 #. y sums the result
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP doesn't accept a list of digits as input (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/255650/sum-every-second-digit-in-a-number?page=2&tab=scoredesc#comment566345_255650), so some kind of variant of `10&#.inv` would be required to convert to digits beforehand

Comment: `1(#.]*0 1$~#),.&.":` adapts your approach to the number input requirement.

Comment: Ah, I see. Appreciate it. Very smart use of `&.` here @Jonah. Will update.

Answer (score 4):

## [pl](https://perl1liner.sourceforge.io) – Perl One-Liner Magic Wand, 12 bytes

Use **-o** to loop over command line arguments. Global matching regexp returns every other character, in this case digit. By default List::Util::sum is imported, `e(cho)` its result. On the [blog](https://perl1liner.sourceforge.io/Challenge-and-Golf/#o-e-sum..g-10-101011-548915381-999999), hover the ▶ button, or the blue code box, to see the result:

```
pl -o 'e sum/.(.)/g' 10 101011 548915381 999999 2147483647 999999999
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Dart (2.18.4)](https://dart.dev/), <s>92</s> 77 bytes

```dart
f(n,[i=1])=>[for(;i<(n='$n').length;i+=2)int.parse(n[i])].reduce((v,e)=>v+e);
```

- [Try it online](https://tio.run/##bYtBDoIwFET3noKFCf8HQiwUgdR6kaaLRoo00S@pyMZ49kqMmxpnVvPypjd@DmEAypWTTKM8quHmQbgDkEy3lGJxsXSeR@EyWaKjuZiMv1sg5TTqwtv@cbIAS27X75JZFOFqHAEmz02STH59wABshyiivZbFrOZtx@qq/cHdJzErGW94W@1588/96q/wBg).
- [Full source](https://github.com/alexrintt/algorithms/tree/master/codegolf/sum-every-second-digit-in-a-number/dart-2.18).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(map(int,f'{n}'[1::2]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6faBvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyM3sUAjM69EJ029Oq9WPdrQysooVlPzf0ERUFAjUcPUxMLS0NTYwhAoBgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 13 bytes

```
2/`1.: map +/
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin)

For testing purposes:

```
"548915381" ; n>o
2/`1.: map +/
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
2/` 1.: map +/
```

- `` 2/` `` chunk into pairs
- `1.: map` get second element of each pair
- `+/` sum

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 12 bytes

```
.(.?)
$1$*
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX09Dz16TS8VQRYtL7/9/QwMuQwMgNOQyNbGwNDQ1tjDksgQDLiNDE3MTC2MzE3OoCBAAAA) Link includes test cases. Takes input as a string because Retina has no integer types. Explanation:

```
.(.?)
$1$*
```

Convert alternate digits to unary, dropping the other digits.

```
.
```

Take the sum and convert back to decimal.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
ＩΣΦＳ﹪κ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEI7g0V8MtM6cktUjDM6@gtCS4BCiXrqGpo@Cbn1Kak6@RraNgpAkC1v//m5pYWBqaGlsY/tctywEA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   Ｓ    Cast the input to string
  Φ     Filter characters where
     κ  Current index
    ﹪ ² Is odd
 Σ      Take the sum
Ｉ       Cast to string
        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 31 bytes

```
@(s)sum(num2str(s)(2:2:end)-48)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjWLO4NFcjrzTXqLikCMjTMLIyskrNS9HUNbHQ/J@mYWigyQUigdAQxDI1sbA0NDW2AHMswQDEMjI0MTexMDYzMUeIg6T@AwA)

This converts the number to a string, sums up the character codes in the string, then subtracts the ASCII code for `0` (48) from each character.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330GjWLO4NFcjrzTXqLikCMjTMLIyskrNS9HUNbHQ/J@mYWigyQUigdAQxDI1sbA0NDW2AHMswQDEMjI0MTexMDYzMUeIg6T@AwA "Octave – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 18 bytes

```
1⊑·+˝⌊‿2⥊'0'-˜•Fmt
```

Anonymous tacit function that takes a number and returns a number. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgMeKKkcK3K8ud4oyK4oC/MuKliicwJy3LnOKAokZtdAoKRiA1NDg5MTUzODE=)

#### Explanation

```
1⊑·+˝⌊‿2⥊'0'-˜•Fmt
               •Fmt  Format as string
          '0'-˜      Subtract '0' character from each, giving a list of digits as numbers
     ⌊‿2⥊           Reshape into an array with two columns, dropping the last digit if
                     there is an odd number of digits
  ·+˝                Sum down each column
1⊑                   Take the element at index 1 (0-indexed) in the resulting list
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$3\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 2.469 bytes

```
S]y
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTXXkiLCJbNSw0LDgsOSwxLDUsMyw4LDFdIl0=)

Port of Vyxal.

```
S]y
    # Uninterleave
 ]  # Get last
S   # Sum
```

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$6\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.939 bytes

```
S-n2'0
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJTLW4yJzAiLCJbNSw0LDgsOSwxLDUsMyw4LDFdIl0=)

My original answer before seeing Vyxal.

```
S-n2'0 # Input as a digit list
  n    # For every
   2   # Second item
    '  # Replace
     0 # With a 0
 -     # Subtract this from the original list
S      # Sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 51 bytes

```
{it.map{it.code-48}.foldIndexed(0){i,a,c->i%2*c+a}}
```

No TIO link as it doesn't have an updated version, ATO borks with it for some reason.

```
{it.map{it.code-48}.foldIndexed(0){i,a,c->i%2*c+a}} // String input
{                                                 } // Lambda expression
 it.map{it.code-48}                                 // Subtract 48 from each char, turning the string into a list of digits
                   .foldIndexed(0){i,a,c->       }  // Fold over the list, starting with 0. i is the index, a is accumulator, and c is the digit
                                          i%2*c     // Multiply the current digit by the index mod 2. If it is even, it resolves to 1*c, otherwise 0*c
                                               +a   // Add to accumulator
```

Comment: [43 bytes](https://pl.kotl.in/-EPqc_5PA) if you map with the index: `{it.mapIndexed{i,a->i%2*(a.code-48)}.sum()}`

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 13 bytes

```
+/(2!!#:)#10\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxFj01ugzAQhdedUxCli0SV4x/AgH2CrnqANFKIMQQl2Ck2Fahqz14TpGRmMfPpvcV7tXjDG7ZarcV2TckngBc/r/vprxd1FEWjPNqL3Bzrsr3KUU6y3x5+g2dPiSSH+w1LJZ3/NMkLmsY5lYzPXNxHsmwGRpMsyWOeZJIVT3U2xMENgOHs/c0JjJWtdGOv9c75Ul30qM6lafRO2Q5/Ddr51hqHWZrylGA3dEh/635CTitrKlS1TetRa1CJzNCddA/wbm6Dj15Cnehj8OEHShYksORfiMKjQSDGYcm3iCyDZ4WABTwKBDXm/3A5VUY=)

- `10\` convert (implicit) input integer to a list of its digits
- `(2!!#:)#` only keep elements at odd indices (0-indexed)
- `+/` calculate (and implicitly return) the sum

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 28 bytes

```
f(n)=sum(digits(n)[2:2:end])
```

Comment: It seems like you can make this a function by adding 5 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P00jT9O2uDRXIzk/ryy1qERPwzOvRCc5PycnNblEo7ikKDMvHagk2sjKyCo1LyVWU1NP18RC838BUKJEI03D1MTC0tDU2MJQU/M/AA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Comment: the current `f(n)=sum(digits(n)[2:2:end])` solution
sums the "every second" digits from the end (right to left). note that the starting index is wrong for even length numbers, for those it should be `1`. one possible formula is `1+end%2`...

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 35 bytes

```c
i;f(n){n=n?f(i=n/10)+i++%2*n%10:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctBCoMwEAXQvacIFmHStJjEmJiK9CLdFDWSRQcpXQji2dM0WNo/u/f/9Oep70PwrQOkK3Z4deA7LAWnzDNWyCMWgl94u4XH3SPQNTsMo/M4khkWSuanx5eDvBhumJ8W2mYzOIjflHxTloTvGk/sTVSRtFaNFXXVpCKq1Iltym8sTWIplFFNpZWJ1Yft33p/iFzpbAtv)

Port of js solution

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 49 bytes

```hs
f s=sum[read[x]|(i,x)<-zip[0..]$show s,mod i 2>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxNCoMwGAX3OUUWLhRU8mms8a/7Qm8gLgKJGqpRjKWh9O6pls7bDY8ZuXnIaXKux6Yxz7ndJBet7T6@Cm1QR2@1tiSOO8@MywubcF4EVji5ks7NXOlGLNjW0SD3u9KyWjeld6/3zwi2ZXnTe1CdPwcEATkGKKOsgCxlgIofKAGaU5ZeaP43B18)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
2ι`SO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6NzOhGD///9NTSwsDU2NLQwB)

#### Explanation

```python
2ι`SO  # Implicit input                          TOP OF STACK:
2ι     # Get every second character              ["58131", "4958"]
  `    # Dump onto the stack                     "4958"
   S   # Cast to a list of characters            ["4", "9", "5", "8"]
    O  # Sum it up (implicit cast to integer)    26
```

Answer (score 3):

## [jonesforth](https://github.com/nornagon/jonesforth/), 104 bytes

```
: F DUP UWIDTH 1 AND IF BASE @ / THEN 0 SWAP BEGIN BASE @ /MOD -ROT + SWAP BASE @ / DUP NOT UNTIL DROP ;
```

Less obfuscated version:

```
: F
    \ make sure we have an even number of digits
    DUP UWIDTH
    1 AND
    IF BASE @ / THEN

    0 SWAP
    ( accumulator value )
    BEGIN
        \ add the smallest digit to the accumulator
        BASE @ /MOD ( acc rem quot )
        -ROT + SWAP
        \ discard the new smallest digit
        BASE @ / ( acc v )
        \ loop until the value is 0
        DUP NOT
    UNTIL
    DROP
;
```

This answer needs UWIDTH, which gforth doesn't have, so I specified jonesforth because it definitely works on jonesforth.

It compiles to 124 bytes, which drops to 116 if you have constants defined for 0 and 1. On a 16 bit forth it would theoretically be half that. Also it has the added bonus of working in any base between 2 and 36.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 61 bytes

```
D=floor(logk)
f(k)=∑_{n=0}^Dmod(n+D,2)mod(floor(k/10^n),10)
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xxkwtnlgsn)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vdlipcgqzy)

There must be some better way to do this other than separating out the `D=floor(logk)` lol.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ġ₂z₁t+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//8jCR01NVY@aGku0//83NbGwNDQ1tjD8HwUA)

*-2 bytes thanks to @DLosc*.

#### Explanation

```
ġ₂         Group consecutive digits into sublists of 2 elements
  z₁       Zip
     t     Tail
       +   Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [*Acc!!*](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/Acc!!), 176 bytes

```python
48
Count i while _%60/48 {
_+_%60*59-2880+0*N+N
}
_/60
Count d while _/10^d {
Count i while 9/(_/10^d)*(d-i+1) {
Write _/10^(d-i)%10+48
}
}
_+1
Count z while 1/_ {
Write 48
2
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETv@YpcCk2Wkt2aluTsvVdvBtsIBkRBKoKSb48JRsHbMjPvsYdlmeeUtGHb6/2y8sAfp3A@cteMqLThL@ag3HKwXW8MAsoJJhaZUyNWxn8ZRbj3GflXWdV@GiFb3wUgkSe7W1grUULREEJ@IhYzUDU8q4GU@yF51LOY0qCNpWFj6A0)

#### Explanation

As often happens with *Acc!!*, the majority of the code is taken up by decimal I/O.

```python
### INPUT AND COMPUTATION ###
# Load a spurious 0 digit into the accumulator
48
# Loop while we just read a digit character and not a newline/eof 
Count i while _%60/48 {
  # Add the digit represented by the character code in _%60 to the running tally in _/60
  _-_%60+60*(_%60-48)
  # Read the next character and do nothing with it
  _+0*N
  # Read the next character and store it in _%60
  _+N
}
# Set the accumulator to the value in _/60
_/60

### OUTPUT ###
# Figure out how many digits the accumulator value has
Count d while _/10^d {
  # Once we're on the leftmost digit, loop a number of times equal to the number of digits
  Count i while 9/(_/10^d)*(d-i+1) {
    # Output each digit from most significant to least significant
    Write _/10^(d-i)%10+48
  }
}
# But if the value was zero, this didn't output anything, so...
# Convert 0 -> 1, other values to numbers greater than 1
_+1
# Loop while accumulator is 1
Count z while 1/_ {
  # Write a 0 character
  Write 48
  # Set accumulator to 2 to break out of the loop
  2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) +coreutils, 29 bytes

```bash
fold -2|cut -c2|paste -sd+|bc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcs7DoMwEAXAq7iPLHl/3n3HAQOiQEokk853N0w/69LPOY/vtaXMo/3vlBuP39LvPeW@fcba5hRSMnA1sYBDWEIrVxUJYYcVjlCCU4UA4kbFggtcofrGBw)

---

**Alternatives** ([38b](https://tio.run/##Dcs7EoIwFAXQraQDxsG8b/LuAlyFOoMgI51FWvYePf1ZX@3ofd@Ob1ra/k7zLbUhj9dpvNOM55QfcsmfYaFz3XpXNnZIcfVAhYqGFSmmGioVThJhjMoFCmh1Jg8hVIPZP/4A), [46b](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kKbE4Y8GCpaUlaboWN_XS8osUqhQy8xQS0vJzUhR0DROsqzU0SrRtM7W1VY3sq6wMNDWta7lSkzPyFVRKILqgmhesMjI0MTexMDYzMYeIAAA))

```bash
echo `sed -E s'/(.)([0-9])/\2+/g'`0|bc
```

```bash
for z in `fold -1`;{((t+=i++%2?z:0));};echo $t
```

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -R, 28 bytes

```
[scan("..")|tonumber%10]|add
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6ODkxT0NJT09Js6YkP680Nym1SNXQILYmMSXl/39TEwtLQ1NjC0MuQwMgAkJDLoSYJRhwGRmamJtYGJuZmENFgOBffkFJZn5e8X/dIAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```
$[n][0loop digits n[a,b][+b]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?QIYUd1)

Answer (score 2):

## [vemf](https://github.com/selaere/vemf), <s>25</s> 8 bytes

*-17 bytes thanks to language creator*

Well this is a fun one.

```
ª‼│%2╕º+
```

[try it online](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/wasm/index.html?code=Ojg0NzKmE7MlMrinKw) - uses 8472 as an example

### Explanation

```
ª‼│%2╕º+

ª        ' convert to string
 ‼       ' repeat each character...
  │%2    ' (index mod 2) times
     ╕º  ' convert them back to numbers
       + ' sum
```

---

Old answer (25 bytes):

```
{`l←╢αª♣ó╕=_1·αª╕‼.l,-:48+
```

[try it online](https://selaere.github.io/vemf/wasm/index.html?code=Ojg0NzJ7YGwatuCmBaK4PV8x%2BuCmuBMubCwtOjQ4Kw)

### Explanation

```
{`l←╢αª♣ó╕=_1·αª╕‼.l,-:48+

{                          ' define function. (closing } optional)

 `l←                       ' make a list:
    ╢                      ' (group next 9 characters)
         ╕                 ' for each element of
       ♣                   ' the domain of
     αª                    ' left argument as string,
        ó                  ' is (-1)^x
          =_1              ' equal to -1?
             ·             ' discard the return value

              αª╕          ' for each character,
                 ‼         ' repeat it
                  .l       ' by the corresponding list entry
                    ,      ' concatenate the resulting list
                     -:48  ' subtract 0x30 from each entry, so 1 maps to 0x01 etc
                         + ' sum
```

Comment: In your explanation of ```│``` in the 8-byte solution, do you mean 'index' (position in the string) instead of 'codepoint' (character value)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Yes, but all `│` does is group the next two characters, equivalent to `(%2)`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda n:sum(int(i)for i in str(n)[1::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyM6M69EI1MzLb9IIVMhM0@huKRII08z2tDKyig2VvN/QRFIPk0DrCqvoLREQxMI/puaWFgamhpbGAIA)

Comment: There's already a shorter Python solution here.

Comment: And if you try and golf this one down, it's just going to converge into that answer.

Comment: **This isn't even golfed.** You have unnecessary square brackets. Also, using `map` instead of a comprehension is another obvious golf, but that will get you to almost exactly the same as the other Python answers.

Comment: @TheThonnu Exactly the reason why I didn’t use it.

Comment: And besides the other answer only works in Python 2. Apparently you’re not paying attention

Comment: You can use `str(n)` instead of `\`n\`` to achieve the same thing. And still, you haven't even removed the *very unnecessary* square brackets.

Comment: Also, when I put this into TIO I got 43 bytes, not 44, so I've updated your answer

Comment: Thanks for that. Those square brackets are required for indexing; you cannot index a generator, if I’m not wrong

Comment: You don't need indexing: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyMzr0QjUzMtv0ghUyEzT6G4pEgjTzPa0MrKKFbzf0ERSDoNoiivoLREQxMI/puaWFgamhpbGAIA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Since you insist, I’ll remove them. Note that using map will effectively make this a port of the other answer which is why I won’t use it.

Comment: Feel free to add a new answer porting the Py2 answer, if you like.

Comment: @TheThonnu one last thing; please be a bit kinder when giving golfing suggestions to others; most people will act more hostile than me when receiving golfing suggestions in such a tone.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
e=lambda n:sum([int(x)for x in str(n)[1::2]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9U2JzE3KSVRIc@quDRXIzozr0SjQjMtv0ihQiEzT6G4pEgjTzPa0MrKKDZW839BEUg@VcPUxMLS0NTYwlBTkwsmZmiAwgFCZFlsOizBAEnAyNDE3MTC2MzEHEMVWOF/AA)

Comment: You can save 10 bytes with: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fahvzPycxNyklUSHPqrg0VyM3sUAjM69Ep7ikSCNPM9rQysooVlPzf0ERUFAjVcPUxMLS0NTYwlBTkwsmZmiAwgFCZFlsOizBAEnAyNDE3MTC2MzEHEMVWOF/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Anonymous function submissions are allowed, so you can remove `e=` to save 2 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
ąĐƩ⇹ƧƩ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9weXT//8SFxJDGqeKHucanxqkt//81NDg5MTUzODE)

```
ąĐƩ⇹ƧƩ-
ą         implicit input (n); convert n to array of digits
 Đ        duplicate top of stack
  Ʃ       sum the digits of n
    ⇹     swap the top two items on the stack
     ƧƩ   sum every other digit of n, starting with the first
      -   subtract; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 53 bytes

```
\X:-get(_),get(C),C>0,Z is X+C-48,\Z;write(X).
:- \0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/PybCSjc9tUQjXlMHRDlr6jjbGehEKWQWK0RoO@uaWOjERFmXF2WWpGpEaOpxWekqxBjo/f9vZGhibmJhbGZiDgA)

Full program.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 4.5 bytes

```
+`%~>>`@~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWK7UTVOvs7BIc6iB8qPDqaFMTC0tDU2MLw1ioEAA)

### Explanation

```
+   Sum of
`%~  select every second element, starting at first, in
>>    remove first element of
`@~    base 10 digits of
        input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
dZlAKS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLUqJyHL2DIRyo2IKVpiYWloamxhaGEAEA)

**Explanation:**

```python
dZlAKS  # Implicit input
d       # Cast to digits
 Zl     # Uninterleave
   AK   # Get last element
     S  # Sum this list
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 42 bytes

Without recursion:

```
n=>[...''+n].reduce((s,n,i)=>s+=i%2&&+n,0)
```

Try it:

```js
f=n=>[...''+n].reduce((s,n,i)=>s+=i%2&&+n,0)

console.log(f(10))         // 0
console.log(f(101011))     // 1
console.log(f(548915381))  // 26
console.log(f(999999))     // 27
console.log(f(2147483647)) // 29
console.log(f(999999999))  // 36
```

Comment: Strangely i got [exactly 42 bytes too](https://tio.run/##bYzRDoIgGEbvewrnloM0BETFC3yR1gUzdDQDl63XJ3K5Fvn9l@f85yqfcu7uenocjb0o1wtnRHtCCJk0js/oJicAVKahaGUq1AHoPYWZFBgmiXSdNbMdFRrtAHpACITRujyPyC7g@JfjP@5vbWz8l4w3pCz4onhOq0Boln0DtA4ESljNeFGx2ktvodksfCJeKCr3Ag) by trying a similar method!

Answer (score 1):

## [Java 8 (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 110 <sup><s>112</s></sup> bytes

> -2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat !

Solution using only a single inline Stream, and using a 2-cell array as the accumulator of the `reduce` to carry both the sum and the index of the current cell.

This could easily be outgolfed by a more classic Java solution.

```java
n->(n+"").chars().mapToObj(e->new int[]{e-48}).reduce(new int[2],(a,b)->new int[]{a[0]+a[1]%2*b[0],++a[1]})[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/disIwEIXvfYpBEJJtG7auQkXWJ3DZC70ruZimqaabpiVJXUT67N1UKuzNcOabH86p8YZJ20lTlz9j1xdaCRAanYMvVAYeiwWAMl7aCoWEYwAATwIVmaqh@0CGac159OH6CBo@R5MciImWS8rEFa0jlDXYndvvoiYyORj5O/3I@UMmm2ygzMqyF5K8@JrHBOOC/t/E/J1HmKd8tX4rgo6jZzfQoMf9ZGC2P/u4taqEJoQgJ2@VueQc0F4cnSOc7s7LhrW9Z10Ye22IZhXZbrJduv3IUvoKNox/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 43 bytes

```lua
a=0(...):gsub('.(.)',load'a=...+a')print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/0dZAQ09PT9Mqvbg0SUNdT0NPU10nJz8xRT3RFiiunaiuWVCUmVeikaj5//9/I0MTcxMLYzMTcwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S`, 1 [byte](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
^
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSU1RSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTU0ODkxNTM4MSZmbGFncz1T)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
^S
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSU1RVMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD01NDg5MTUzODEmZmxhZ3M9)

##### Explanation

```python
^S  # Implicit input  ->  548915381
^   # Uninterleave    ->  [5,8,1,3,1], [4,9,5,8]
 S  # Sum the list    ->  [5,8,1,3,1], 26
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 38 bytes (APL SBCS)

```
λ x \⌿⊙← + \⍠¨ *&[$(^mod 2)#0]\⌹⊙ 10 x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEKjZTUNIU0BY2lpSVpuhY3Tc7tVqhQiHnUs_9R18xHbRMUtIGc3gWHVihoqUWraMTl5qcoGGkqG8QClewEKlEwNFCogOjdr6nJxaWRmW9VXpRZkpqTp6CRpmBkaGJuYmFsZmKuqQlRtWABhAYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 112 bytes

```rkt
((λ(l)(for/sum([i(range(length l))]#:when(odd? i))(-(char->integer(list-ref l i))48)))(string->list(~a(read))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jco7DsIwEIThq1hKM1tYvAIEinAQRGHFG8fCONLaiI6LcQeuZBxRzv@NmOHOuTTBRKfkP4DvB4EwzrJKzweuHlKZETi6PKlAdGvOr4kjZmsvyhNBY5iM6N7HzI4FwaeshUcVFm47qp@UxUen@8XwNhA2tnYqZbPdtfvDsTutfw)

---

### Explanation

Creates an anonymous function that receives user input as a list of characters. It then iterates through the length of the list. If the index is an odd number, we transform the current charater into a digit and add it to the sum.

```rkt
((lambda (lst)
   (for/sum ([index (range (length lst))]
             #:when (odd? index))
     (- (char->integer (list-ref lst index)) 48)))
 (string->list (~a (read))))
```

#### The mysterious "89" with no input

If you supply this program with no input, you will notice that the final sum would be 89.

That is because we convert the result of `read` directly into a string.

```rkt
(~a (read))
```

When there is no input, the `read` function returns `#<eof>`. Our code converts the `#<eof>` symbol to a string, `"#<eof>"`. Then it loops through all the characters that have odd indices, giving us a list of `'(#\< #\o #\>)`. After that, the characters are converted into ASCII numbers. Since the ASCII value of "0" is 48, we subtract 48 from the result:

```rkt
; (x - 48 becomes y)
'((#\<  12)
  (#\o  63)
  (#\>  14))
```

The numbers are then summed together to get 89.

---

*Have a wonderful week ahead!*

Answer (score 0):

## [Matlab](https://la.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 166 bytes

```matlab
n = input('Input : ', 's');
d = str2double(regexp(n,'\d','match')); %convert n to a unidimensional matrix 
total = 0; %stores total sum
    for i = 2:2:length(d) %traverse the unidimensional matrix [ vector ]
        total = total + d(i); %sum of every second n
    end
disp(['Output : ', num2str(total)]);
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833) This site is for competitive programming, so we require answers to aim to shorten their code as much as possible (such as removing whitespace, getting rid of input prompts, etc.). Make sure to read our [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips?tab=Votes) questions if you want some hints!

Answer (score 0):

## Java 19, 100 bytes

Partial program assuming `n` is the given number:

```java
var m=0;var s=String.valueOf(n);for(var i=1;i<s.length();i+=2)m+=s.charAt(i)-48;System.out.print(m);
```

Full program using standard input:

```java
interface A{
    static void main(String[]a){
        var n=Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
        //
        var m=0;
        var s=String.valueOf(n);
        for(var i=1;i<s.length();i+=2)m+=s.charAt(i)-48;
        System.out.print(m);
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Commodore BASIC (C64/128, C16/+4, VIC-20, PET, THEC64 Mini/THEC64/THEVIC20) - 88 BASIC Bytes

```
0 inputn$:iflen(n$)=0thenend
1 iflen(n$)<2orval(n$)<9then3
2 fori=2tolen(n$)step2:n=n+val(mid$(n$,i,1)):next
3 printn
```

A quick explanation

- Line zero waits for an input; if there is no input, then the program is ended
- Line one checks if the length of the input is 1 character, or the value is fewer than 9, if so, we branch to line 3
- Line two iterates over the string from the second character, and each second character thereafter until the end of the string. The value of each is added to `n` (which will be zero before the `for/next` loop).
- Line 3 outputs the total sum on `n`

[image: Sum every second digit in a number, Commodore C64]